# Will calling subject.OnCompleted() tidy up/ call dispose/not leak memory or do I have to call dispose on the IDisposable myself?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Rx question please, will calling subject.OnCompleted() tidy up/ call dispose /not leak memory or do I have to call dispose on the return IDisposable myself?

Basically I'm making a server request/response and want to know if the client code needs to call replaySubject.Dispose() in the example below.

Thanks in advance.

```
            try
            {
                object response = Send(msg);
                replaySubject.OnNext(response);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                replaySubject.OnError(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                replaySubject.OnCompleted();
            }
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `ReplaySubjects`, you should dispose of them to have them deterministically release their internal replay buffers.  Note that once you dispose of them, any future subscribers will not be able to see the replayed events.  So do not dispose of them if you still need them to "replay".

If you don't care about determinism, then just releasing references to them after they are completed is sufficient -- their buffers will get cleaned up when the subjects are garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Standard practice dictates that if you are responsible for creating a resource, then you are responsible for disposing of that resource. If the `ReplaySubject`/resource is defined as a field in a class, then the class itself should implement `IDisposable`. In that classes `Dispose()` method the field should inturn be disposed. If the `ReplaySubject`/resource is defined in a closure (e.g. in an Observable.Create) then expose a way to dispose that resource bound to the closure (maybe by returning an `IDisposable` like `Observable.Create` does)

It is also worth asking the question, why are you using a Subject? Can you not just the `.Replay(1)` operator?

Comment: `Replay(1)` where?